# What is the best practice to reconstruct relationships between branches imported from VSS to TFS?

Tags: tfs, migration, visual-sourcesafe

I have the following branches of the same project in VSS. The common files are shared between those projects as it used to be in VSS.

- MyProject-v1
- MyProject-v1.1 - branched from v1
- MyProject-v2.0 - branched from v1
- MyProject-v2.1 - branched from v2
- MyProject-v3.0 - branched from v2

What is the best practice to reconstruct this relationships after I migrate to TFS2010 so that we benefit from the new branching/merging features in TFS?

Comment: You should learn how branching works in TFS 2010. You may decided to dump your VSS branches entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The best strategy is posted at by Richard Banks: http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/09/how-to-fix-branches-after-migration-to.html. It concerns using a baseless merge. This needs to be performed from the commandline using the tf command.